# how to fix loop of errors with gradle versions?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I received Android Studio project from friend using git.
When I tried to sync the gradle files, I got this error:

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.1.

So I changed the gradle version in gradle-wrapper.proprties but then I got this error:

> Error:No such property: GradleVersion for class: JetGradlePlugin

I searched for solution here for this error and I saw that the solution is to downgrade version but when I did it, I got the previous error..
What can I do to fix that loop?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest path is to download an older Android Studio version that works with your project.

The upgrade path is better for the long run but may force you to fix a number of things before getting to a working setup.